# Android, write to file using inheritance

Tags: android, writetofile

I am currently saving a message to a single file from multiple activity classes within my app. Each activity class has the same function WriteToFile.

```
public void WriteToFile(String info) {

    FileOutputStream FoutS = null;
    OutputStreamWriter outSW = null;

    try {

        FoutS = openFileOutput("file.txt", MODE_PRIVATE);
        outSW = new OutputStreamWriter(FoutS);
        outSW.write(info);
        outSW.flush();
    }

    catch (Exception e) {
    }

    finally {
        try {
            outSW.close();
            FoutS.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }
}
```

I have been attempting to create a separate class which holds this function write (and read) to file but I haven't been able to without getting errors.

I think the function needs to have context passed through to the WriteToFile void like...

```
    //Changes to this line
 public void WriteToFile(String info, Context context) {

    FileOutputStream FoutS = null;
    OutputStreamWriter outSW = null;

    try {
                      //Changes to this line
        FoutS = context.openFileOutput("file.txt", MODE_PRIVATE);
        outSW = new OutputStreamWriter(FoutS);
        outSW.write(info);
        outSW.flush();
    }

    catch (Exception e) {
    }

    finally {
        try {
            outSW.close();
            FoutS.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }
}
```

if that is correct am I passing the context correctly?

```
String msg = "This is a message";

WriteToFile(msg, this);
```

It's not working so I am doing something wrong.

Comment: If you could post the stack trace you are seeing that would help (you might want to remove your catch statement to ensure the exception gets thrown up the stack).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use your context to call the method

```
 context.openFileOutput("file.txt", context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

what you wrote has no meaning, or far from what you mean.